# Is there a way to get a Callable back from a FutureTask?

Tags: java, future, callable

If I have a `FutureTask<String> f,` can I get the `Callable<String> c` object that was used in his constructor?

Something like:

```
Callable<String> c = f.getCallable();
```

Comment: FutureTask is not final, so...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not with `FutureTask` itself, but you could extend it for your own needs:

```
class YourFutureTask extends FutureTask<String> {

  private Callable<String> callable;

  public YourFutureTask(Callable<String> callable){
     super(callable);
     this.callable = callable;
  }

  public Callable<String> getCallable(){
     return callable;
  }
}
```